# Alternatives to presentational html tags

Tags: html, css

I have a headline on my website and i have to break some words and place on the second row and some words are in different colour. Is there a way i could do that without using the presentational html tags like line break 
 and emphasis ? Im very new in html and css.

```
<h1 class="header" >I AM A <em>SURFER</em> <br/> WHO LOVES THE BEACH, <br/> SUNSET AND ICE CREAM.</h1>
```

Comment: `<em>` is *not* presentational.

Comment: This is correct way i hope, if you want to use color add span for seperate text

Comment: Neither `<em>` nor `<br>` is classified as presentational, though according to HTML5, the latter should be used only when the data itself contains a line break. But what is the practical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Bonus: you can have lowercase letters in your HTML code and obtain the same visual result than your example with CSS: `h1 { text-transform: uppercase; }` (related accessibility Technique: [Using CSS to control visual presentation of text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/C22.html) that will allow some users to adapt the latter to their needs and preferences)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela We have website project in school and on the requirement we are not allowed to use <em> and <br> tags on html so we have to figure out how to style it on css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the existing class and tag you've specified, you could roll with something like the following:

**CSS:**

```
span.header h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="header"><h1>I AM A <em>SURFER</em></h1><h1>WHO LOVES THE BEACH,</h1><h1>SUNSET AND ICE CREAM.</h1></span>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to have more than two h1 in a page? Just a question coz im i newbie in coding.

Comment: Yes, you can use more than one <h1> tag on a page, in fact, you are not limited in using multiple instances of _any_ HTML tag on a given page. Tag away at will!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `span` that you will then display as blocks.

HTML:

```
<p><span>hello></span><span>How are you</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
p span 
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @user2828816: please make use of my second answer as it is more user friedly. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
```

Note: I just pressed enter key for new line.

Answer (score 0):

If it is (absurdly) forbidden to use `em` and `br` markup, then you can use the `span` element and CSS rules that correspond to the default rendering of those elements:

```
<style>
.em { font-style: italic }
.br:after { content: '\a'; ; white-space: pre }
</style>
...
<h1 class="header" >I AM A <span class="em">SURFER</span> <span class="br"></span>
WHO LOVES THE BEACH, <span class="br"></span> SUNSET AND ICE CREAM.</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! i have tried all the answers here and they all worked :). I just had a little problem with the white-space though when i tried to add media queries on css. The gap in between the 'white space' is too much when i try to view the website on my mobile.